# How I can disable some languages in Geonetwork

Tags: geonetwork

Please, how I can display just some languages in Geonetwork?
I edit thes files, but I don't see any change in the dropdown menu to select the language, In fact , I want just those languages: French, English and Arabic, but actually I see all languages that are by default in Geonetwork.

config-gui.xml

```
    <languages>
        <ara/>
        <eng/>
        <fre/>     
    </languages>
```

js/CatControllers.js:

```
    $scope.langs = {'eng': 'en', 'fre': 'fr', 'ara': 'ar'};
    $scope.langLabels = {'eng': 'English', 'fre': 'Français', 'ara': 'Arabe'};
```

web-inf/config-spring-geonetwork.xml

```
    <util:set id="languages" value-type="java.lang.String">
       <value>ara</value>
       <value>eng</value>
       <value>fre</value>
    </util:set>
```

Comment: Welcome.  When you say you don't see any change, what exactly do you mean?  What are you expecting vs. what results? Where are you looking when you don't see the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You did right changes in CatControllers.js, but you need to delete these files for changes to be visible:
-wro4j-cache.h2.db
-wro4j-cache.lock.db
-wro4j-cache.lock.db